# How do I grab all children nodes under the parent node in xml using flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, adobe

I have a parent node and I'm trying to get each child node under that parent and store it into an arraycollection? How could I go by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var coll:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

for each ( var child:XML in parent.children()) {
    coll.add(child);
}
```

parent.children() gives you all child nodes of parent as XMLList. You can then add each child to the collection.

If you want to include only element nodes, you can use elements() instead of children().